# Attach jQuery's resizable handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

See this [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e865rerd/4/).

I'm trying to attach the handlers to resize `$('oWrapper_'+num)`. But it doesn't resize. The reason is because `$('#oWrapper_'+num)`, is not yet added to the dom when this is executed, so the selector won't return any element.

How do I resize `$('oWrapper_'+num)` instead of resizing `cloudWrap`?

```
num++
    var cloudWrap = $('<div />', { id: 'cloudWrap_'+num}),
        outerWrap = $('<div />').appendTo(cloudWrap)

        outerWrap.append(
            $('<div />', { class: 'tf', id: 'oWrapper_'+num, style: 'white-space:pre-line; font-size: 2vw;' }),
            $('<div />', { class: 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne hndl' }),
            $('<div />', { class: 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se hndl' }),
            $('<div />', { class: 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw hndl' }),
            $('<div />', { class: 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw hndl' })
        );


        jQuery('#oWrapper_'+num).resizable({
          handles: {
            'ne': '.ui-resizable-ne',
            'se': '.ui-resizable-se',
            'sw': '.ui-resizable-sw',
            'nw': '.ui-resizable-nw'
          },
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        });
```

Comment: your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d85ubukk/) doesn't show anything

Comment: @HowardRenollet: Apologies. I've updated it with the correct link now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e865rerd/15/) and see if this solves your problem.

```
var num = 0;

num++;
var cloudWrap = $('<div />', { id: 'cloudWrap_'+num}),
    outerWrap = $('<div />').appendTo(cloudWrap);

outerWrap.append(
    $('<div />', { class: 'tf', id: 'oWrapper_'+num, style: 'white-space:pre-line; font-size: 2vw;' })
);

cloudWrap.appendTo('body');

$("#oWrapper_" + num).resizable({
    handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw',
    aspectRatio: true,
});
```

Your custom css classes were interfering with jQuery-UI's classes that are added when `.resizable()` is called.

Also, I moved the `.resizable()` call to the end of the code block to ensure that the element is present in the DOM before it's called.

If this isn't what you were looking for, or if I misunderstood something, please let me know and I will make the necessary changes.  Thanks!

Comment: When the classes are removed from `$('<div />', { class: 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne hndl' }),` the handlerd doesn't show at all? Strange what might be the reason?

Comment: You actually don't need those extra div's for the handles.  jQuery-UI adds divs for the handles.  Do you see the handles in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e865rerd/13/?

Comment: I'm using jquery ui 1.11.3. There seems to be a difference in the syntax? E.g.: `aspectRatio: true,` and `aspectRatio: 16 / 9,`. See this with v1.11.3: http://jsfiddle.net/e865rerd/14/

Comment: See the fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/e865rerd/15/.  It's not a problem with the syntax.  Since you loaded jQuery-UI as an external resource, you have to load the jQuery-UI css file as well.  Also - there are some minor tweaks needed to the css - on `.ui-resizable-handle` and on `.ui-resizable-se`.  All changes are shown on the fiddle.  Let me know if there's anything else I can help you with.

Comment: Thanks Howard got it now!! One additional question.Is it possible call an function after the resize is completed? E.g.: Once the mouse is released run this `furni(document.getElementById('cloth3'));` ?

Comment: No problem.  Yes, absolutely.  You can use the [stop event](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-stop) to run a function after the resize has completed.  Here's a quick example:  http://jsfiddle.net/e865rerd/16/

Comment: I figureout the cause for the issue. Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/e865rerd/18/ . Why does the keyup() function affect the handlers? how can i fix this?

Comment: Because changing the HTML of the parent `<div>` removes the handles that jQuery-UI inserts.  The best way to do this would be to make a repeatable function to add the resize ability back to the div.  I've added a `makeResizable()` function to the code.  I also changed the event handler to `.change()`  http://jsfiddle.net/e865rerd/19/